# How to populate data from uitextfield to a uitableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I created three textfields food name, food quantity, sodium amount. When I click the submit button I'd like to update a tableview with the data from the textfields. I created an NSObject as well as established logs to show the data is being saved from the textfield and the submit will move to the tableview but I can't get the data from the textfield to display

Comment: Did you `[tableView reloadData];`?

Comment: some code would be helpful too :)

Comment: Please avoid asking the same question repeatedly to draw attention to it. Thanks!